# Android how to save SD file to cloud

Tags: android, file, cloud, sd-card, android-backup-service

I try to save/backup sd files on cloud but can't find a way to do this.

I see `BackupAgentHelper` but it's said on doc it's only for `sharedPreferences` or internal files.

Here is a way to use `FileBackupHelper` with a file on SD card ? Or maybe I have to use another feature for backup ?

I try this :

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+Globals.BASE_PATH);
    FileBackupHelper helper = new FileBackupHelper(this, root.getAbsolutePath());
    addHelper(FILES_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
```

But it's not working...

**Fixed : I use DropBox API to backup/restore**

Comment: Do you have a running web-service / web application running somewhere? Because, you might want to expose a back-up service API, and just use it to upload that file to your own server using http verbs, to and from your back-end.

Comment: no i don't use web-service with my application. it's why i search with FileBackupHelper cause it manage files alone.

Comment: First, if you aren't trying to merely backup configurations or preferences - like if u want to backup sizable binary files, then i recommend u consider using a web-service or some provider that exposes this service via say an intent like that.

Comment: Thanks actually there is no way on Android API to do this so i implemented Dropbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android save/backup API is not useful in my case cause i want to save SD files... so i have to use external save/backup system like GDrive or DropBox. I choose DropBox cause it's works really good and it's really simple to use.